# Keeping data when using mapply in R

Tags: r, mapply

I have a data frame I am applying a function to using `mapply()`, but my result doesn't keep certain info in the initial data frame that I would like to keep. The function I am applying across the data frame is not vectorized.

**DATA FRAME**

```
Dealer  Cities                  Zip     Radius in miles     
A       Rancho Cucamonga, CA    91730   40  
A       San Bernardino, CA      92401   40  
B       Chino, CA               91710   40  
B       Fontana, CA             92337   40
```

I am applying a function that gets all zip codes in the given mile radius of the initial zip.

```
remotes::install_github("EAVWing/ZipRadius")

results <-  with(city_names, mapply(ZipRadius::zipRadius, 
                             as.character(`Center Zip Code`),`Radius in miles`, SIMPLIFY =FALSE ))
```

**RESULT**

The result is a large list containing a data frame for each time the function `zipRadius` was called.

[image]

[image]

**DESIRED RESULT**

Each data frame contains the zip code used by the function and the data the function generates, but I would like it to also keep the corresponding "Dealer" column associated with each initial Zip.

For example, the above data frame is generated from the zip 91730, which has a Dealer value of A.

```
DEALER   ZIP      Other columns generated by the function...
A        90001 
A        90002
A        90011
```

Comment: `dplyr::left_join(city_names, dplyr::bind_rows(results, id ='zip1'), by = c(zip='zip1'))`

Comment: @lmonninger that is not correct

Comment: @Onyambu I get an error, `Error: Argument 2 must have names.` I think it has to do with `dplyr::bind_rows(results, id ='zip1')` What is the id argument trying to grab?

Comment: Sorry it should be `.id='zip1'` I forgot the period

Comment: @Onyambu `Error: Join columns must be present in data. x Problem with `zip`.`

Comment: That is a quick fix you can do. You have `Zip` and not `zip`. write `by =c(Zip = 'zip1')` instead of what I have

Comment: @Onyambu I get the same error.
`dplyr::left_join(city_names, dplyr::bind_rows(results, .id ='zip1'),  by =c(Zip = 'zip1'))`

`Error: Join columns must be present in data. x Problem with `Zip`.`

Comment: @Onyambu Wait i think this is my fault, The actual name of the column in the initial data frame is Center Zip Code, i shortened it for simplicity. '

Comment: I am unable to help with no reproducible example.Ensure the joining columns are present in the original dataframe.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240485/discussion-between-jacob-nordstrom-and-onyambu).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Onyambu gave me a great solution in the comments ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70499816/keeping-data-when-using-mapply-in-r/70500088#comment124622403_70499816)):

```
dplyr::left_join(city_names, dplyr::bind_rows(results, .id ='zip1'),  
                  by =c(Zip= 'zip1'))
```